# How to determine if a polynomial is bounded from below?

Tags: polynomials, multivariate-polynomial

Given the coefficients of a multivariable polynomial, how can I determine if it's bounded from below? In other words, given a polynomial $p\left(x_1,x_2,...x_n\right)$, does there exist a real number $C$ such that $p\left(x_1,x_2,...x_n\right) \ge C$?

I do not need to find the minimum value of the polynomial, I just want to know whether or not it is bounded.

Comment: This is related to the research problem "sum of squares."

Answer (score 5):

Deciding whether the polynomial

$$p (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) - c$$

is globally nonnegative is not easy. Fortunately, deciding whether $p (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) - c$ can be written as a **sum of squares** (SOS) is easy, as the decision procedure is a semidefinite program, which is in [P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_(complexity)). However, not all globally nonnegative polynomials can be written as a sum of squares.

From one of Parrilo's papers [0], an example to clarify the above:

---

[image]

---

[0] Pablo Parrilo, [Semidefinite programming relaxations for semialgebraic problems](http://www.mit.edu/~parrilo/pubs/files/SDPrelaxations.pdf), 2001.

Comment: So, given a homogeneous polynomial of even degree in several variables, can be tell whether it is positive at infinity?

Comment: Understood, I am trying to figure out what is going on; one sufficient condition for the whole polynomial to have a lower bound is for the highest degree homogeneous part to be strictly positive at infinity, meaning strictly positive on the standard unit sphere. Sorry for, well, changing the subject a bit.

Comment: @WillJagy As I am not a mathematician, I am not qualified to comment on that. From a computational viewpoint, one finds a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix via semidefinite programming, then one obtains the SOS decomposition via Cholesky decomposition. There is some "voodoo magic" here, as the SDP solver uses floating-point numbers and may produce an SOS decomposition that is not quite exact. If one used arbitrary-precision rational numbers, it would be nicer, but slower.

Comment: Rodrigo, thank you. I will read up a bit on Hilbert's 17th problem, see whether  my sub-problem  is known.

Comment: The paper I linked to above has lots of references. Another one is: Pablo A. Parrilo, Bernd Sturmfels, [Minimizing Polynomial Functions](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0103170), arXiv:math/0103170.

Comment: Excellent. The problem I made up is known but far more difficult than I thought... see the example " p is homogeneous of even degree " in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_polynomial#Examples  The article by Reznick is available online.