# Deciding whether a given polynomial is globally positive

Tags: polynomials

In general, is there any efficient approach to determine if a polynomial
over $\mathbb{R}$ is positive?

The only constraint here is that the polynomial can only have a maximum of 5 or 10 variables. If so, there is an available tool to use, maybe something that you tried before?

Comment: By positive, you mean $f(x)$ is positive for all $x\in\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2102418/339790).

Comment: Here is a rather fortunate [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2414847).